# How to truncate characters in product description with WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have found out how to add a short description to the thumbnails for products in WooCommerce, but how do I truncate them to a certain length, say 30 characters.
All the answers to do with editing the functions.php file dont mention where in the file to put the code.

**My code in my functions.php file is:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','add_title_description',9);
function add_title_description(){
  echo get_post_meta($product->id, 'title-description', true)? '<span class="title-description">' . get_post_meta($product->id, 'title-description', true) . '</span><br />' : '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [substr()](https://www.php.net/substr)

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','add_title_description',9);

function add_title_description()
{
    $titleDescription = get_post_meta($product->id, 'title-description', true);

    if( !empty($titleDescription) )
    {
        if( strlen($titleDescription) > 30 )
            $titleDescription = substr($titleDescription, 30);

            printf('<span class="title-description">%s</span><br />', $titleDescription);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My implementation grabbing the first 2 sentences instead of a character count.

```
/**
* Echo Truncated String
*
* @param  string $string
* @return string
*/

function add_title_description( $titleDescription ) {
global $product;

    $titleDescription = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'title-description', true );
    
    // combine first 2 sentences
    $sentence = preg_split( '/(\.|!|\?)\s/', $titleDescription, 3, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
    
    echo $titleDescription ? '<span class="title-description">' . $sentence[0] . $sentence[3] . '</span><br />' : '';

}


add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_title_description', 4, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this:

```
    function wcs_excerpt_length( $length ) {
     return 15;
}
add_filter( 'product_description_length', 'wcs_excerpt_length' );
```